# iOS ChildViewController has different view

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uiscrollview

I have a container view controller and two child view controller (CV1 and CV2). CV1 has a scroll view and CV2 has UITableView, I'm successfully able to with between child view controllers, but it seems CV1 is adding ~64 padding at the top but not for CV2. And navigation bar is hidden for both.
I'm using this code:

```
-(void)displayContentController:(UIViewController *)content withFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    [self addChildViewController:content];
    content.view.frame = frame;
    [self.view addSubview:content.view];
    [content didMoveToParentViewController:self];
}
```

I've double checked that I'm passing the correct value for `frame` Still CV1 is adding extra space

Comment: can u explain little much

Comment: This is a wried behaviour, I have never come across such situation, hence the question.  It seems its adding some additional points for CV1view frame (upon examining the frame it is return correct frame(0,54,320,514)) **but** the view is not positioned where it supposed to be(i.e. the view is at (0, 118, 320,514)).

Comment: Have you used Xcode's view debugging feature?  It can tell you what logic (constraints) is being used to calculate view positions and sizes.

Comment: Thanks @Phillip Mills, Xcode's view debug helped. I was  adding an explicit height constraint on view. Thanks for all the answers.

Comment: Just a follow-up question, if the constraint was added then why it did't show up in the Xcode inspector ?

Answer (score 0):

1. Check that the scroll view in CV1 doesn't have a constraint to `topLayoutGuide`
2. Try overriding `automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets` of CV1 and return `NO`